# Binding model to template with emberjs

Tags: templates, ember.js, render

I am going to bind model to template with emberjs

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="dashboard">
    <div>
        <span>this is user list</span>
        <div>
            {{render userinfo userinfo}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_userinfo">
   {{#each model}}
   <span>{{user}}
   {{/each}}
</script>

App.Userinfo= DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Userinfo.FIXTURES = [
    {user:"user1"},
    {user:"user2"},
    {user:"user3"}
];

App.UserinfoView= Ember.View.extend({
});

App.UserinfoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({   
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('dashboard', {path: '/dashboard'}, function() {
    });
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('dashboard', {      // the template to render
          controller: 'dashboard'       // the controller to use for the template
        }); 
    }
});

App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
});
```

When i go to /#/dashboard, Dashboard template is loaded.
In here, I have rendered userinfo.
I'd like to bind Userinfo Model to usersinfo template so that I display all users.
Help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short:** here a working [jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/ibehim/2/edit)

**The long:** You hade slightly to much unnecessary going on in your code, basically this does the job:

First of all you had no redirect to your `dashboard` route, since it's your only route (at least as far I can see from your code) we redirect directly to it after entering the `index` route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('dashboard');
  }
});
```

I've removed the `DashboardController` since there is nothing to be done.
Then your `DashboardRoute` was missing the `model` hook to provide actually data for your `dashboard` template

```
App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Userinfo.find();
  }
});
```

In the router map you don't need to define a `path` if the URL is the same name as your template name in your case it is the same `dashboard`

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('dashboard');
});
```

The userinfo model was correct

```
App.Userinfo= DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.attr("string")
});
```

But your fixtures where missing the `id`

```
App.Userinfo.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, user:"user1"},
  {id:2, user:"user2"},
  {id:3, user:"user3"}
];
```

Moreover you where using the `render` helper with a `partial` template `_userinfo` the correct way to render a `partial` is this

```
{{partial userinfo}}
```

As you can see we don't pass any additional parameters to it because the data will be made available trough your `model` hook. The `partial` helper uses the context and the data provided in the template it is rendered into, in your case the `dashboard` template, therefore the `model` hook is necessary.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. and then I have to go to dashboard when i click login button. so i think i have not to use the function like transitionTo.    how do i have to do now at that time?